# Select N locations from list to maximize sum, with min distance constraint

Tags: algorithm

I want to select 5 localities out of 250 locations, to maximize expected profit such that minimum distance between each locality is 5 miles.  Expected profit associated with each location and distance between them is given.

I was trying to find out if this is a standard problem. Applying filters to arrive at the solution seems computationally intensive. I have been exploring methods like simulated annealing to reach at a good enough solution.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just to be clear, by `maximize expected profit such that minimum distance between each locality is 5 miles` you man you want 5 selected localities whose sum of profits is maximized over the set AND where the distance between any two localities within these 5 is greater than or equal to 5 miles?

Comment: This doesn't sound that computationally expensive at all, you could surely brute force a "best 5 out of 250" with ease.

Comment: I doubt you'd even have to brute force it.  It's really just a maximum subset problem (which is O(k*n)) which relatively simple pair-constraints.  A "Greedy Pairs" algorithm O(k*n^2) would probably be *very* close to optimal.

Comment: Generically, it's a maximum-profit packing problem, and NP-hard. Binomial[250, 5] is less than 8e9; surely that's not too many possibilities.

Comment: @mbratch Yes. You are right.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl If it were something like 25 out of 250 I still want this algorithm to work

Comment: @RBarryYoung Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @san8055 Do the distances have any structure to them? (Triangle inequality? Euclidean? almost Euclidean?)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat latitude and longitude are available.. used haversine formula to get the distance.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - 250.choose.5 is 2E12.  250.choose.25 is 6E36.  Brute force is looking mighty unattractive.

Comment: @pjs Presumably the combinations aren't ordered.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - That's why I evaluated choose rather than permute.  Permutations would be much worse.

Comment: @pjs Check your math then?

Comment: Please improve the title. As written, it is not helpful to any future visitor who may have the same problem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You're right, arithmetic error. 7.8E9 and 1.6E34, respectively for 250.choose.5 and 250.choose.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using great-circle distances, there are a couple possibilities that provide some quality guarantee: approximation schemes for Euclidean graphs, and integer programming. The former is in theory more scalable, but the latter gives exact optima and is a lot easier to implement assuming that a solver is available. (Of course, you could always do something ad hoc.) Since you have so few locations, that's the one I'll describe.

I'll explain integer programs briefly by formulating your problem as one.

```
maximize profit1 * x1 + profit2 * x2 + ... + profit250 * x250
subject to
x1 + x2 + ... + x250 = 5  (select exactly 5 localities)
for every pair of localities {i, j} less than 5 miles from each other,
    xi + xj <= 1
x1, x2, ..., x250 in {0, 1}
```

The meaning of variable `xi` is that it's 1 if locality `i` is selected and 0 if locality `i` is not selected.

You'll need to write a small subroutine to communicate this program to your favorite solver in its preferred format. To find a solver, search for "MIP solver"; there are free and commercial offerings with bindings to a variety of languages. Try to get one that supports clique cuts (I know the commercial CPLEX and the free GLPK do). If it doesn't, that's OK; you can implement Bron–Kerbosch yourself to generate constraints of the form

```
xa + xb + ... + xz <= 1
```

where `a, b, ..., z` are localities each within 5 miles of one another.