# How to select n objects from a set of N objects, maximizing the sum of pairwise distances between them

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, euclidean-distance

You have a set of N=400 objects, each having its own coordinates in a, say, 19-dimensional space.

You calculate the (Euclidean) distance matrix (all pairwise distances).

Now you want to select n=50 objects, such that the sum of all pairwise distances between the selected objects is maximal.

I devised a way to solve this by linear programming (code below, for a smaller example), but it seems inefficient to me, because I am using N*(N-1)/2 binary variables, corresponding to all the non-redundant elements of the distance matrix, and then a lot of constraints to ensure self-consistency of the solution vector.

I suspect there must be a simpler approach, where only N variables are used, but I can't immediately think of one.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696033/select-n-locations-from-list-to-maximize-sum-with-min-distance-constraint) briefly mentions some 'Bron–Kerbosch' algorithm, which apparently addresses the distance sum part.
But in that example the sum of distances is a specific number, so I don't see a direct application to my case.

I had a brief look at quadratic programming, but again I could not see the  immediate parallel with my case, although the 'b %*% bT' matrix, where b is the (column) binary solution vector, could in theory be used to multiply the distance matrix, etc.; but I'm really not familiar with this technique.

Could anyone please advise (/point me to other posts explaining) if and how this kind of problem can be solved by linear programming using only N binary variables?
Or provide any other advice on how to tackle the problem more efficiently?

Thanks!

PS: here's the code I referred to above.

```
require(Matrix)

#distmat defined manually for this example as a sparseMatrix
distmat <- sparseMatrix(i=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),rep(4,1)),j=c(2:5,3:5,4:5,5:5),x=c(0.3,0.2,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.75,0.6,0.6,0.15))

N = 5
n = 3

distmat_summary <- summary(distmat)
distmat_summary["ID"] <- 1:NROW(distmat_summary)
i.mat <- xtabs(~i+ID,distmat_summary,sparse=T)
j.mat <- xtabs(~j+ID,distmat_summary,sparse=T)
ij.mat <- rbind(i.mat,"5"=rep(0,10))+rbind("1"=rep(0,10),j.mat)
ij.mat.rowSums <- rowSums(ij.mat)
ij.diag.mat <- .sparseDiagonal(n=length(ij.mat.rowSums),-ij.mat.rowSums)
colnames(ij.diag.mat) <- dimnames(ij.mat)[[1]]
mat <- rbind(cbind(ij.mat,ij.diag.mat),cbind(ij.mat,ij.diag.mat),c(rep(0,NCOL(ij.mat)),rep(1,NROW(ij.mat)) ))

dir <- c(rep("<=",NROW(ij.mat)),rep(">=",NROW(ij.mat)),"==")
rhs <- c(rep(0,NROW(ij.mat)),1-unname(ij.mat.rowSums),n)

obj <- xtabs(x~ID,distmat_summary)
obj <- c(obj,setNames(rep(0, NROW(ij.mat)), dimnames(ij.mat)[[1]]))

if (length(find.package(package="Rsymphony",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("Rsymphony")
require(Rsymphony)
LP.sol <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj,mat,dir,rhs,types="B",max=TRUE)
items.sol <- (names(obj)[(1+NCOL(ij.mat)):(NCOL(ij.mat)+NROW(ij.mat))])[as.logical(LP.sol$solution[(1+NCOL(ij.mat)):(NCOL(ij.mat)+NROW(ij.mat))])]
items.sol
ID.sol <- names(obj)[1:NCOL(ij.mat)][as.logical(LP.sol$solution[1:NCOL(ij.mat)])]
as.data.frame(distmat_summary[distmat_summary$ID %in% ID.sol,])
```

Comment: Cplex and Gurobi have options to linearize the quadratic problem automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you Erwin; indeed, after further reading, I am planning to get Cplex. First I'll evaluate the free version, and if it solves the problem formulated as quadratic, I won't even bother with linearizations. But it may not, and in any case the linearization of quadratic problems is an interesting topic; in fact I am going to ask another question about it.

Comment: OP has posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832079/best-linearization-for-p-dispersion-maxmin-problem) whose answers may be applicable to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called the ***p*-dispersion-sum** problem. It can be formulated using *N* binary variables, but using quadratic terms. As far as I know, it is not possible to formulate it with only *N* binary variables in a *linear* program.

[This paper by Pisinger](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1eb3/810077c0af9d46ed5ff2b0819d954c97dcae.pdf) gives the quadratic formulation and discusses bounds and a branch-and-bound algorithm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thank you!
Do you have any recommendations on what quadratic solver to use in R? https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: Looks like there are no free MIQP solvers for R. Rcplex is only an interface and requires installing cplex separately. Linearization seems my only viable solution for now... Many articles like [this one](https://home.gwu.edu/~sagca/NRL.pdf) and [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221716310736) describe techniques to improve the computational efficiency of linearized methods, but I was hoping not to have to code them myself...