# clustering with size constraints and min overlap between clusters

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to place this problem theoretically and I wonder if anyone could please help / point me in the right direction.

Suppose you have a collection of objects (each uniquely identified by `ID`), each having some features (contained in property `FP`). The R script below makes a collection of N = 20 such objects in data.frame `dd`:

```
set.seed(12345)
d <- sample(1:5,20,replace = T)
dd <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind,sapply(d,function(n) list(sample(LETTERS,n)),simplify = F))),"FP")
dd["ID"] <- 1:NROW(dd)
```

I need to separate these objects into 2 sets (or clusters), one of which must have exactly n (say 7) objects, in such a way that the overlap of features `FP` between the two clusters is minimal.

To be clear about what I call overlap, if I made a cluster with the first 7 rows of `dd` (and therefore the other cluster with the last 13 rows), the overlap would be 12:

```
length(intersect(unique(unlist(dd[1:7,"FP"])),unique(unlist(dd[8:20,"FP"]))))
#[1] 12
```

For this simple example I can solve the problem by enumerating all the possibilities and looking at which clusters give the smallest overlap (which shows that there are degenerate solutions and the minimal possible overlap is 4):

```
gr <- t(combn(1:20,7))

result <- apply(gr,1,function(ids) {
  length(intersect(unique(unlist(dd[ids,"FP"])),unique(unlist(dd[(1:20)[!(1:20 %in% ids)],"FP"]))))
})

result <- data.frame("cl1"=apply(gr,1,function(ids) paste(ids,collapse=",")),"overlap"=result)

min(result$overlap)
#[1] 4
```

However, how would you tackle this for larger problems where the brute-force approach is unfeasible?
And in some cases I may need to make more than 2 clusters, which doesn't help.

I am thinking linear programming for still tractable cases, or some approximate method for more challenging ones, but I would not know where to start looking for packages or literature.

I know how to make a selection of objects whose set of unique features is maximized or minimized, using LP, but this seems quite different to me - or am I wrong?

---

**EDIT 1**: work in progress

Perhaps this task is similar to the p-dispersion problem that was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832079/best-linearization-for-p-dispersion-maxmin-problem).
Except of course for the fact that in this case I need to select the n objects that are as far as possible not from one another, but from the set of unselected N-n objects. I guess the code could be adapted; not sure exactly how, yet.
But having to calculate the pairwise distance matrix may be a big limitation when N is larger than 10000. So approximate methods may be useful here.

If I stack the original data, treating the features in `FP` as binary variables, and then tabulate:

```
ddu <- do.call(rbind,sapply(dd$ID,function(x) {data.frame("ID"=x,"FP"=unlist(dd[dd$ID == x,"FP"]),stringsAsFactors = F)},simplify = F))

ddu.tab <- xtabs(~ID+FP,ddu,sparse = T)
ddu.tab

#20 x 23 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#   [[ suppressing 23 column names ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’ ... ]]
#                                                
#1  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 .
#2  1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
#3  . . 1 . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
#4  . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#5  . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . 1 1 . . . . . .
#6  . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . .
#7  . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . .
#8  . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . .
#9  . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
#10 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
#12 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . .
#13 . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . . .
#14 . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . .
#15 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . 1
#16 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . .
#17 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
#18 . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1
#19 . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 .
#20 . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

If I had a single cluster with all the N objects, of course all features would be present:

```
colSums(ddu.tab)
#B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q S T V W X Y Z 
#2 5 2 4 1 1 1 2 4 4 2 2 1 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 4 2
```

Looking at the `colSums` for one of the optimal solutions found by brute force (objects 1,2,4,10,11,12,17):

```
colSums(ddu.tab[c(1,2,4,10,11,12,17),])
#B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q S T V W X Y Z 
#2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 2 0
```

And its complement:

```
colSums(ddu.tab[-c(1,2,4,10,11,12,17),])
#B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q S T V W X Y Z 
#0 5 2 4 0 1 1 2 4 2 0 2 1 2 0 4 3 0 1 3 2 2 2
```

In an iterative procedure, one may start with one empty cluster `CL1` and the full set as the other cluster `CL2`, and at each iteration find the object in `CL2` to move to `CL1` by looking for the minimal overlap, stopping when `CL1` has n objects. Example:

```
CL1 <- numeric(0)
CL2 <- 1:20

while (length(CL1) < 7) {
ov <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(CL2)) {
  tCL1 <- c(CL1,CL2[i])
  tCL2 <- CL2[-i]
  ov <- c(ov,sum(as.logical(colSums(ddu.tab[tCL1,,drop=F]))*as.logical(colSums(ddu.tab[tCL2,,drop=F]))))
}

i <- which.min(ov)
CL1 <- c(CL1,CL2[i])
CL2 <- CL2[-i]
}
```

In this case this produces a solution with an overlap of 6, so not optimal (4).

If anyone has got suggestions on how to improve this (or do this completely differently), they would be welcome.

---

**EDIT 2**

A rather obvious fact had escaped me.
In the above example there are in total M = 23 features. If cluster 1 contains m1 features and cluster 2 contains m2 features, in all cases M = m1 + m2 - overlap. This seems to imply that minimizing the overlap (which in the above code requires a *product* of two binary vectors) is equivalent to minimizing the sum m1+m2 (which is the *sum* of two binary vectors). I checked that numerically using the brute force solutions, and indeed the expected linear relationship is found.

As m1+m2 can be obtained by linear programming using N+2*M binary variables, it is in theory possible to solve this without calculating the pairwise distance matrix.